# Html template assignment in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, email, let

Lets say I have the below HTML Template whats the best way to assign it to a variable in Angular Project

```
public template = '<html><body> <p>This is a p tag</p>

     </body></html>'
```

How do I make such kind of assignment in typescript?

Comment: The code in the question does not work?

Comment: Its just a html tag

Comment: I meant if its a big template whats the best way to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a project that work with Angular 7.^, you can use a binding with

```html
<div [innerHtml]='template"></div>
```

Where `template` is declared in component like

```js
template = '</p>This is a p ta</p>'
```

If your version is older then 7 you must sanitize your bindig with

```html
<div [innerHTML]="template | safeHtml"></div>
```

Anyway, why declare a variables public if is the default value?

Answer (score 0):

```
public template = '<p>This is a p tag</p>'
```

In the Html

```
<div [innerHtml]="template"></div>
```

Comment: if its a big html template how can we include it in a new file and assign it to a variable?